# prevent scrolling of overflow:hidden elements when link to anchors are clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

clicking the link the anchor is reached, but even if the parent element has overflow:hidden
it scrolls unnecessarily hiding the contents

```
<style>
div#x
    {overflow:hidden;border-bottom:1px red solid;}

div#x > div
    {border:1px red solid;padding:10px;float:left;width:33%;box-sizing:border-box;padding-bottom:10000px;margin-bottom:-10000px;}
</style>

<div id="x">
    <div><a href="#test">go to</a><br><br>a</div>
    <div>a<br><br><br><br>a</div>
    <div>a<br><br><br><br><br><br><span id="test">go here</span></div>
</div>
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aj8cX/5/

is there a way to fix this behavior?

Comment: Note that this isn't a bug - `overflow: hidden` elements are still supposed to scroll if necessary, they just aren't supposed to display UI controls for doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some javascript trickery.

I am using jQuery, but you can use anything you want.

```
$('a[href="#test"]').on('click', function(){
    var test_element = $('#test');
    var scroll_top = test_element.scrollTop();
    var max_height = test_element.parent().height();
    if (scroll_top < max_height) { return false; }
    else { return true; } //only scroll if the item is in view
});
```

Comment: why not just use event.preventDefault(); wont that prevent the move to anchor?

Comment: @PatrickEvans The OP **wants** to scroll to the item, but not if it is out of the viewport.

Comment: Idk... why make a element have hidden content and have an anchor to it ? :P

Comment: of course i want to go to the item, but i want to use the body's scrollbar to reach it, not the overflow:hidden element :P

Comment: this is a common used hack to create equal heights columns, but it has this problem with anchors, so, i don't think it's silly trying to identify the best solution for handling this.

Comment: i thought the example was clear enough... what can i say... it's my bad

Answer (score 1):

This is as close as I could get, using `table > table-cell`:

http://jsfiddle.net/mikedidthis/AmNxf/

Would work well for static content, but for dynamic content it may cause some issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to get elements of equal height:

```
var height = 0;
$.each($('#x div'),function(k,v){
    if($(this).height() > height){
        height = $(this).height();
    }
});
$.each($('#x div'),function(){
    $(this).height(height);
});
```

Fix your css like so:

```
div#x
{
    overflow:visible;
    height:10000px;
}

div#x  div
{
    border:1px red solid;
    float:left;
    width:33%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin-right:-1px;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/aj8cX/6/

Comment: that doesn't even look remotely similar to the original.